# How does one get the dbt power user extension in vscode to actually work? I have one and clicked to update it but got an error

Tags: dbt

I got two errors. The first is :

```
Error while updating 'dbt Power User' extension. Please check the [log](command:workbench.action.showWindowLog) for more details.
```

The second error is:

```
[2022-09-27 09:21:53.593] [renderer4] [error] [Extension Host] (node:16272) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `Code --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[2022-09-27 09:21:55.813] [renderer4] [error] XHR failed: Download: XHR failed
    at G.downloadExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/josh/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:170479)
    at async G.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/josh/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:169610)
[2022-09-27 09:22:05.897] [renderer4] [error] ["Download: XHR failed","    at G.downloadExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/josh/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:170479)","    at async G.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/josh/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:169610)"]
[2022-09-27 09:22:05.916] [renderer4] [error] XHR failed: Download: XHR failed
    at G.downloadExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/josh/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:170479)
    at async G.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/josh/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:169610)
[2022-09-27 09:30:55.976] [renderer4] [error] ["Download: XHR failed","    at G.downloadExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/josh/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:170479)","    at async G.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/josh/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:169610)"]
[2022-09-27 09:30:56.023] [renderer4] [error] XHR failed: Download: XHR failed
    at G.downloadExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/josh/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:170479)
    at async G.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/josh/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:83:169610)
```